# Очистка очереди канала

Tags: golang

Необходимо с помощью канала асинхронно передать данные из одной части программы в другую. Каким образом правильно реализовать передачу, чтобы получатель вынимал из канала всегда последнее сообщение?

Обычная работа буферизированного канала по принципу FIFO не подходит. Полный FILO мне тоже не нужен, т.к. меня интересует только последнее сообщение.
Я использую канал с буфером равным 1 и перед отправкой сообщения каждый раз его очищаю:

```
    select {
    case <-d.someСhan:
    default:
    }
```

Это гарантирует, что после отправки в буфере канал находиться последнее самое свежее сообщение. Но если получатель захочет получить сообщение в момент между очисткой и отправкой, то он не получит ничего. Сообщение пропадет.

Мне не нравиться ситуация с возможной потерей и сама конструкция выглядит как костыль. Возможно есть более прямые способы реализовать функционал асинхронной отправки, чтобы последнее сообщение вытесняло предыдущие.

**UPD** такая незамысловатая диаграмма
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а почему бы принимающей стороне не выгребать сообщения. Но в любом случае, опишите саму задачу, которую Вы решаете, возможно, у нее есть готовое хорошее решение. А пока похоже, что просто нужна глобальная переменная с мютексом.

Comment: Это драйвер устройства, от устройства состояние поступает  когда угодно и в любых количествах, но обрабатываются эти данные допустим раз в секунду, поэтому интересует только самое последнее. Сейчас есть реализация на мьютексах и по причине железа новая идея - это перейти полностью на синхронную работу или каналы, где синхронизация не возможна в принципе. Для выгребания на стороне приема нужен большой буфер что тоже не лучшее решение.

Comment: тогда делайте так - пришло событие, обработали, запомнили время. Когда пришло следующее, посмотрели сколько времени прошло. Если времени недостаточно прошло, просто игнорируем, много - обрабатывам

Comment: Мы должны обрабатывать каждой событие, приходящее от устройства, ведь мы не знаем когда придет следующее, может даже никогда. Можно копить события и организовать передачу данных в канал за какое то время до следующего такта обработки, но это становится достаточно дорого по количеству кода и по вычислительным ресурсам. Там встроенное решение.  Время наступления следующего такта обработки  тоже величина неизвестная, в идеале это случается не по внутреннему таймеру, а по внешнему сигналу на ножке процессора. Хочется сделать чтобы данные асинхронно лились, и вынимались только самые последние.

Comment: Похоже, что ответ на Ваш вопрос - никак. Если источник не будет присылать данных, то обработчик не сможет получить последнее сообщение. Но если все таки там железное решение, можно попробовать сделать flip-flop - то есть у нас не очередь, а два буфера и флажок. В результате, читающая сторона будет всегда читать последнее событие и переключать флажок. Источник данных будет писать в противоположный буфер

Comment: Как вариант да, можно попробовать так